# Leaking Service held by Coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to dive into coroutines world, trying to make some network work in `Service` (in fact `LifecycleService`). after starting it I'm calling below method

```
private fun runConnectionCoroutine() {
    job = lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            doSomeNetworking()
            if (!isActive) return@launch
            publishResult()
        }catch (e: CancellationException){
        }
    }
}
```

`doSomeNetworking()` may take too much time, so user should be able to dimiss this task and `Service`. I'm calling then `job?.cancel()` and then `stopSelf()`. As expected coroutine doesn't stop immediatelly (thats why `if (!isActive) return@launch` line is there), but `Service` does and [leakcanary](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/) detects: `CoroutineScheduler$Worker` keeps reference to this `Service`

so the question is: how to properly stop `Service` during networking coroutine?

Comment: This is actually a very interesting question. I guess it is not always possible to not leak anything at least for a fraction of a second. I don't know leakcanary, so I'm not sure if it allows some time margin or not. Still, your code isn't really very cancellation-friendly. As you noticed, it can cancel only after the long running operation finishes, so this `isActive` check does not make too much of a difference. What we need to do is to check for `isActive` **during** the long running task. And do it regularly, e.g. each 100ms.

Comment: Specific solution depends on your implementation of `doSomeNetworking()`. If you are performing blocking I/O reads then usually there are some alternatives to do it in a non-blocking way or at least to specify a timeout. This way you can read data and at the same time verify `isActive` status frequently. You can also switch I/O API/library to one that is fully non-blocking, e.g.: `okio` or `NIO`, etc.

Comment: `doSomeNetworking()` in my case is using [GRPC](https://grpc.io/) and I've configured some timeouts, but still there is a case, when networking starts at some point and after 10 ms `Service` gets killed for some not-networking-related reason (e.g. user desire). I'm canceling `job` in `onDestroy`, but this coroutine still works and hold reference to killed `Service`, so leak... anyway, dzięki za komentarz

Comment: Does [suspendCancellableCoroutine](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/suspend-cancellable-coroutine.html) help you?

Comment: @RickyMo can you post some example usage of this method?